# How to manually clear the apache cache for .htpasswd?

Tags: apache, .htpasswd

I changed the password in .htpasswd for basic auth, but I could not break the cache on the old .htpasswd without putting credntials direct into the URL. Restarting apache didn't help. I don't want to break/prevent cache-ing on every request, I just want to be able to clear the cache manually when e.g. after a change of password. Thanks.